# How list of lists iteration is working in python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have a list of list like this:-

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9]]
```

If I run these I got output like these.I am not getting how these are working.

```
>>>[j for i in lst for j in i]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>>[j for j in i for i in lst]
[8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

Can anyone please explain how those are giving output like this.what is the differnt between this two iteration?

Comment: Hint: `list` is a reserverd Python word. Don't use it as a name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At the end of first LC `i` is assigned to `[8,9]`:

```
>>> lis = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9]]
>>> [j for i in lis for j in i]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> i
[8, 9]
```

Now in the second LC you're iterating over this `i`:

```
>>> [j for j in i for i in lis]
[8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

Both LC's are (roughly)equivalent to:

```
>>> lis = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9]]
>>> for i in lis:
...     for j in i:
...         print j,
...         
1 2 3 4 5 6 4 5 6 7 8 9
>>> i
[8, 9]
>>> for j in i:
...     for i in lis:
...         print j,
...         
8 8 8 8 9 9 9 9
```

---

[**This has been fixed in py3.x**](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax):

> in particular the loop control variables are no longer leaked into the
>   surrounding scope.

Demo(py 3.x):

```
>>> lis = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8, 9]]
>>> [j for i in lis for j in i]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> i
Traceback (most recent call last):
NameError: name 'i' is not defined

>>> j
Traceback (most recent call last):
NameError: name 'j' is not defined
```

Comment: I guess this python 2.x related as the locals of a comprehension still leak, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Hyperboreus Yes, this has been fixed in py3.x

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary thanks a lot.From your post i got what i wanted to know.thaks once again.

Answer (score 1):

```
[j for i in list for j in i]
```

This is similar to

```
result = []
for i in list:
    for j in i:
        result.append(j)
```

In general the list comprehension like `[p for a in b if c == d for e in f if etc]` will be translated to like

```
reuslt = []
for a in b: if c == d: for e in f: if etc: result.append(p)
```

---

```
[j for j in i for i in list]
```

Normally this won't even run. Probably you have defined `i` to be `[8, 9]` previously.

```
>>> [j for j in i for i in list]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

This is equivalent to

```
result = []
for j in i: 
    for i in list:
        result.append(j)
```

so if `i` is not defined at first, the loop will not work.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: You'd get NameError if you run `[j for j in i for i in list]` alone (without running `[j for i in list for j in i]` first).